# Bootstrap4 - Center text in col and match width / height of other col in row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

EDIT: I have a jsfiddle now [https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/jshet597/8/] (make sure to resize the html part more to the left so that the two blocks appear side-by-side)

Hello I have Box1 and Box2 side-by-side, Box1 will always have less text in it than Box2, so I'm trying to make it so Box1 will center its text and stretch the box's width/height to match the space availaible due to Box2 (right)

[image]

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Box1 (left) -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style=height:100%>
        <div class="card-body ">
        <div class="row ">
            Box1 text 
        </div> <!-- / .row -->
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /col -->
    
    <!-- Box2 (right) -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style=height:100%>
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row align-items-center mb-4">
          <div class="col">
            Box 2 text ...
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I want Box1 text to be centered, while the box's width and height still matches that of Box2. In the above image the width and height is responsive and perfect, but the text isnt centered.

If I add ' my-auto' to box1's col definition like so:

```
 <!-- Box1 (left) -->
    <div class="col-md-4 my-auto">
```

It gets there partially, the text is now centered (Nice!) but the box doens't fill out the empty space to match Box2

[image]

Is there a way to style my boxes such that Box1's text will be centered, as well as filling out the empty space to match that of Box2?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to check the jsfiddle I added in my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the classes `h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center` on the parent `.row` of `Box1 Text`:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Box1 (left) -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style=height:100%>
        <div class="card-body ">
          <div class="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
            Box1 text
          </div>
          <!-- / .row -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /col -->

    <!-- Box2 (right) -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style=height:100%>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row align-items-center mb-4">
            <div class="col">
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
              Box 2 text ... Box 2 text ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: im sorry but in my code (which I'm having trouble posting exactly but will try later) adding `h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center` does nothing

Comment: EDIT: I have a jsfiddle now [https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/jshet597/8/] (make sure to resize the html part more to the left so that the two blocks appear side-by-side)

Comment: @Martin Forked here https://jsfiddle.net/z8k1wqrm/ You need to remove class `my-auto` from `col-md-8`

Comment: @Martin Another thing you should keep in mind for the future, always try to inspect the elements in dev tools to see which classes are being applied, you almost always get useful insights from it

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6" >
          <p>Box one</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can try this to align your items center
Use these classes on container `h-100` on row `h-100` `align-items-center` `justify-content-center`
these classes will align your items into center

Comment: I tried adding  those to this jsfiddle but it sadly didnt make a difference: https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/jshet597/11

Comment: You need to understand which item needed to be aligned in center. before aligning center you need to define the height of the parent element. It'll work if the parent element height is defined.
Suppose you need to align your row in center the you should define the height of container. if the container height is 200px and row is 100% that means they both have same height and when you call center in row, It'll divide the height of row and will align into center.
I believe this will work

Comment: I've tried setting the row's style to include "height:100%" but I'm not getting any changes; could you help me illustrate that in this jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/jshet597/15/

Comment: try this [Code From JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devhabib/gxn9ctvq/1/)
Let me tell you something. Row is flex but it doesn't contain any height. container also doesn't have any height. Whatever content you put in your container the it gets the height from the content. when you define container height 100%, It will get the 100% height of it's parent div. so whenever you wanna use `align-items-center`, before calling the class define it's parent div a height with (`px`, `em`, `rem`) or whatever you like but don't use percentage as height because it comes from it's parent div.